# How do I search for list items in string in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
urlList = ["https://google.com","https://google.com/help","https://facebook.com","https://facebook.com/help","https://facebook.com/test"]

filterKeys = ["help","test"]

clearUrl = []

for i in urlList:
   if filterKeys not in i:  #TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
      clearUrl.append(i)
```

Expected output ['https://google.com', 'https://facebook.com']

Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you're exactly trying to achieve from the above snippet? A sample expected output?

Comment: Is your expected output `['https://google.com',
 'https://facebook.com']`?

Answer (score 1):

The error is raised because you are using the `in` operator in a wrong way:

`in` works as follows:

```
"string" in <collection>
```

The problem in your code is that you used:

```
<collection> in "string"
```

Try instead:

```
for i in urlList:
    if not any(map(lambda fk: fk in i, filterKeys)):
        # any will return True if at least of one the filterKeys is substring of i
        clearUrl.append(i)
```

Comment: Oh Thank you! I used this and with `else` it worked.

Comment: @Nozoom you don't need `else`, use `not` in your condition. I've updated my solution.